# Definite Integral

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Solve the following : $$\int_0^1 x^5 \sqrt{1 - x^2}dx $$

Any ideas ?I haven't been able to make any progress on this exercise , it's driving me insane , since there's probably no big deal to the solution.. Thanks a lot in advance for your patience !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

$$\int_0^1x^5\sqrt{1-x^2}\ dx=\int_0^1 x^4\sqrt{1-x^2}\ xdx$$

Set $\displaystyle 1-x^2=y^2\implies x\ dx=-y\ dy$ and $x^2=1-y^2$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input !